# Any way to run an executable as a system user / administrator?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to take advantage of the devcon tool inside my program. But devcon requires elevation of UAC. I see that if i run it with administrative command prompt it works, but any way to trigger this? I know how i can require my entire program to elevate, but i want normal non-admins to be able to use this.

Especially looking to use devcon.exe /rescan so normal users can check for drivers.

Comment: Use `Process` class with `runas` as verb. There are tons of existing discussions.

Comment: Are you suggesting that your program should run in a non-elevated state but be able to perform actions that require elevation?

Comment: Obviously the purpose of the UAC is to prevent so usage. Microsoft made a lot of effort to try to stop people like you to do suspicious activities on a computer without the user knowing about it. **Stop trying to hack the UAC.** People like you are contributing to make Windows slow because it has to work harder preventing bad software to do bad things on the system.

Answer (score 2):

When you configure the `ProcessStartInfo`, set `UseShellExectue` to `true` and `Verb` to `runas` in order to see the UAC window:

```
ProcessStartInfo process= new ProcessStartInfo(locationOfDevconExe);
   process.UseShellExecute = true;
   process.Verb = "runas";
```

If you still can't see the UAC window, then it is defined in the registry key `ConsentPromptBehaviorUser` to automatically deny. The key should be located under this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

So change the value from 0 (deny automatically) to 1 (display the prompt).